# fairseq package installs outside virtual environment but not inside a virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, pypi

I have tried creating new virtual environments but it is still not working. i keep on getting the following error

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\manzo\desktop\venv\ofa\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\manzo\desktop\venv\ofa\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\manzo\desktop\venv\ofa\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\manzo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_r1xkhki\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 178, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\manzo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_r1xkhki\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 159, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\manzo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_r1xkhki\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 274, in <module>
      OSError: symbolic link privilege not held
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

However when I try to install the same package using the same method outside of a virtual environment, everything installs perfectly. I am trying to install the package by cloning the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq
cd fairseq
pip install --editable ./
```

I am using python 3.7.0. My virtual environment is in a folder on desktop and my project is in another folder on desktop.